# Correct pipeline for container-based AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, fastapi, cicd, aws-fargate

I'm curious about CI/CD for an AWS Fargate service. Suppose that you have a FastAPI (or insert framework) backend running on a container. Now suppose that you develop a new route (or insert code change) and commit. What's the 'golden path' approach to testing and deploying such code?

Broadly, I see two options:

1. Build the container locally, run unit tests, push the container to ECR and (force) deploy the service.
2. Commit changes, pipeline first builds the container, then runs unit and integration tests, then (assuming successful tests) advanced to production.

Comment: Route 1 could be automated as well right? Enjoyed your condescending tone ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modifications to the app code, assuming you're talking about the "best" way to deploy things on an EKS+Fargate or ECS+Fargate environment, i'd bet on codepipeline + codedeploy.

ArgoCD ought to work, assuming you're talking about infrastructure as code and the Gitops approach.